# Closed form for any Turing computable function?

Tags: closed-form, turing-machines

A while back, someone posted (as an answer or a comment) a link to his paper showing that any Turing computable function had a closed form.

In both the comment and the paper itself, he freely and humorously admitted that he was stretching the definition of closed-form to the breaking point.

Does anyone know where I can find that paper and/or a general proof/method to convert Turing machines to closed form formulas?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I have ever seen Kleene post on this site, but [his normal form theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_T_predicate) is the usual normal form for computable functions.

If we look at r.e. sets instead of at computable functions, the MRDP theorem has a corollary that for every r.e. set of naturals $A$ there is a multivariate polynomial $p(\bar x)$ with integer coefficients and integer variables, so that $A$ is the intersection of $\mathbb{N}$ with the range of $p$. In this sense $p$ is a closed form for the Turing machine that enumerates $A$.